# Android Compose cannot preview composable function in android studio "Rendering problem "

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am failing to preview a composable function shown in the code below

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun StartingConversationInstructions() {
    Column {
        Text(stringResource(id = R.string.remember))

    }
}
```

but I am getting this error when I am trying to preview the function

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'androidx.compose.runtime.SlotTable
androidx.compose.runtime.Composer.getSlotTable()'   at 
androidx.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:63)   at 
androidx.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:357)   at
 androidx.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:-1)   at
 androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)   at 
androidx.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:356)   at 
androidx.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:397)   at 
androidx.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AmbientsKt.ProvideCommonAmbients(Ambients.kt:274)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidAmbientsKt$ProvideAndroidAmbients$3.invoke(AndroidAmbients.kt:176)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidAmbientsKt$ProvideAndroidAmbients$3.invoke(AndroidAmbients.kt:-1)   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidAmbientsKt.ProvideAndroidAmbients(AndroidAmbients.kt:168)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.kt:251)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.AmbientKt.Providers(Ambient.kt:188)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:250)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:-1)   at 
.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:146)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambda.invoke(ComposableLambda.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:2904)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.Composer.composeInitial(Composer.kt:2070)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:353)   at 
androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:109)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:235)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.kt:545) 
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.kt:226)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.kt:275)   at 
androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)   at 
androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:233)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:-1)   at 
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.kt:610)   at 
android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)   at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)   at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)   at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)   at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)   at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)   at 
android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44) Copy stack to clipboard  
 Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

I am using android studio version: **Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 4** 
And Android Compose version :**1.0.0-alpha09** 
which I think is the cause of the problem because as you can find in the [changes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-runtime#1.0.0-alpha09) in this version

> Removed SlotTable, SlotReader and SlotWriter from the public API. These were marked as InternalComposeAPI previously. Now they are internal to the compose module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In you dependencies, change

```
implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
```

to

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
```

Does that work?

Comment: Since I tried this,  I have been stuck at a build error `startElement.getAttributeByName(QName("name")) must not be null`

Comment: I think there is a problem with your String resource. Please check the doc here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop#compose-in-views. Try it with a hard coded String to see if it's that.

Comment: sadly `"androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"` didn't solve it.

Comment: the problem mentioned in the comment is strangely related to a string array in the string resources file.
anyway  sadly i'm still facing the same issue

Comment: It seems the problem was even though I did what in the answer,
the preview annotation in my file was imported from the old dependency

Answer (score -3):

As the @author states in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699408/android-compose-cannot-preview-composable-function-in-android-studio-rendering?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+stackoverflow%2FOxiZ+%28%5Bandroid+questions%5D%29#comment116221922_65700310) there are two identical annotations:

```
import androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
```

the second one worked for me.